# Worklight 6.0 development server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with worklight 6.0 server in my localsystem. sice it has working fine but unfortunate is not working b'cos i am getting error from my development console,

Error : CWWKO0030E: An exception was generated when starting chain CHAIN-defaultHttpEndpoint because of exception com.ibm.wsspi.channelfw.exception.ChannelException: TCP Channel: defaultHttpEndpoint- Problem occurred while starting channel: Unable to establish loopback connection.FWLSE2002W: No active IPv4 address was found

I try to change the port but is not started. please help me  ASAP

Thanks
karthik

Comment: Try restarting. Make sure the new port is not already used. Try killing Java and try again.

Comment: I also try this but server is not started while i am getting error for : worklight server CHAIN-defaultHttpEndpoint because of exception.